# Gstreamer and libcamera `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "libcamerasrc"`

Tags: gstreamer, libcamera, arducam

Running a gstreamer pipeline using `libcamerasrc` results in this error:

`gst-launch-1.0 libcamerasrc` gives `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "libcamerasrc"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `libcamerasrc` support isn't in the standard installation of libcamera,
it is in the arducam installation:

```
wget -O install_pivariety_pkgs.sh https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arducam-Pivariety-V4L2-Driver/releases/download/install_script/install_pivariety_pkgs.sh
chmod +x install_pivariety_pkgs.sh
./install_pivariety_pkgs.sh -p libcamera_dev    <-- This contains support for gstreamer's libcamerasrc
```

Look for proof that the arducam package is installed:

```
$ sudo apt show libcamera0

Package: libcamera0
Version: 0~git20230724+ad9428b4-1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: libcamera
Maintainer: Arducam <support@arducam.com>
```

And here is the real proof:
`gst-inspect-1.0 libcamerasrc`